# How to use :value and v-model together in input

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to set an initial value to `v-model` where `id` has already been declared in `data`. However it shows error when compile.

```
<input clearable
       v-model="id"
       :value="id"
       @keydown="isNumber"
       autofocus/>
```

> :value="id" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

Any suggestion to solve the issue ?

Comment: remove `:value="id"`

Comment: @Bravo I need the `input` field with an initial value? If I remove `:value="id"`, how do I assign a value to `v-model="id"` ?

Comment: You could assign a default value to `id` in data property

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly what I've said in my answer below: i.e *the latter (i.e. v-model) expands to a value binding internally*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

```
v-model="id"
```

Does the same as

```
:value="id"
@input="id = $event.target.value"
```

Therefore you don't need to ADD `:value=id`, it's already "there"

---

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

```
<input v-model="searchText">
```

does the same thing as:

```
<input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value"
>
```

so ... you're attempting to do the following

```
<input
    clearable
    
    v-bind:value="id"
    v-on:input="id = $event.target.value"

    :value="id"
    @keydown="isNumber"
    autofocus
>
```

Now since `:value="id"` is [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) for `v-bind:value="id"`, you can now see that you are trying to do

```
v-bind:value="id"
```

twice